# Error: object "ip" is unknown , try "ip help"

Tags: scripts, executable, ip, filename

I am trying to run trusted executables through a script.

I copied the binary executable `/bin/ip` to a directory called `Tools`.

I renamed the binary to `eip`.

I have navigated to the directory tools and tried to run the executable `eip`.

```
# ./eip addr list
```

It throws an error: `object "ip" is unknown , try "ip help."`

How to deal with this?

Comment: are you giving it an IP address where it says "addr"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you keep your local `ip` executable called `ip`, and not something longer, you can avoid this particular problem. If you rename it to some other one or two character long name, that will also work fine--the problem only happens if its name is three or more characters in length. This may seem strange... so read on for details...*

When I run a copy of `/bin/ip` called `eip`, I get an error message with `p` (rather than `ip`) as the unknown object:

```
Object "p" is unknown, try "ip help".
```

I'm wondering if the same is happening to you? (Could there be a typo in your question?) Even if not, I strongly suspect the behavior on your machine is related to what I am seeing.

I found that when I renamed `ip` to anything longer than two characters, it gave me an "unknown object" error about the rest of the characters:

```
ek@Io:~$ cp /bin/ip abc
ek@Io:~$ ./abc
Object "c" is unknown, try "ip help".
ek@Io:~$ mv abc foobar
ek@Io:~$ ./foobar
Object "obar" is unknown, try "ip help".
ek@Io:~$ mv foobar 12345
ek@Io:~$ ./12345
Object "345" is unknown, try "ip help".
```

[`man ip`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man8/ip.8.html) didn't seem to explain this odd behavior, but I did notice that the first non-option argument to `ip` is technically called an *object*:

```
SYNOPSIS
       ip [ OPTIONS ] OBJECT { COMMAND | help }

       ip [ -force ] -batch filename

       OBJECT := { link | addr | addrlabel | route | rule | neigh | ntable |
               tunnel | tuntap | maddr | mroute | mrule | monitor | xfrm |
               netns | l2tp | tcp_metrics }

....
```

So I tried changing the characters, after the first two, to these object names:

```
ek@Io:~$ mv 12345 12addr
ek@Io:~$ ./12addr
1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
....
```

```
ek@Io:~$ mv 12addr XXrule
ek@Io:~$ ./XXrule 
0:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

```
ek@Io:~$ mv XXrule ipl2tp
ek@Io:~$ ./ipl2tp 
Usage: ip l2tp add tunnel
          remote ADDR local ADDR
....
```

So it appears `ip` is designed to check the name with which it has been invoked, and if it contains more than two characters, to interpret the remaining characters as the name of the object on which to operate. Probably this is so that copies and symbolic links of `ip` with names like `iplink`, `ipaddr`, `ipaddrlabel`, and so forth, can act as if `ip link`, `ip addr`, `ip addrlabel`, and so on correspondingly were run.

To double check this, I took at look at the source code. The `iproute2` package provides `/bin/ip`, so I [searched for that](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+search?text=iproute2) and found it to be provided by [the source package of the same name](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/iproute2). (This is often but not always the case.) In [the code tab](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/iproute2), I [selected a branch](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/iproute2/vivid) and [browsed the code](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/iproute2/vivid/files), entering [the `ip` directory](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/iproute2/vivid/files/head:/ip/) and examining **[`ip.c`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/iproute2/vivid/view/head:/ip/ip.c)**.

I looked in the `main` function, since that's where most C programs start running. This is the function that begins:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
```

Like many programs' `main` functions, it consists largely of processing for [command-line options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command-line_option). But below that, there's code to handle the various ways `ip` may be run, and one of them is *for when its name is more than two characters long*:

```
if (strlen(basename) > 2)
        return do_cmd(basename+2, argc, argv);
```

Cool! (Kinda weird--but cool.)

---

The simplest and best solution is probably just to keep your copy of `ip` called `ip`, or some other one- or two-character name. Giving it the same name as the copy of `ip` in `/bin` (and pointed to by the `/sbin/ip` symlink) should not be a problem--your script is already providing a path to the specific executable you wish to run.

However, you might want it to be possible for users to invoke your copy of `ip` with a command like `eip`--for example, so they can have a separate command to put in directories in their `PATH`. This is commonly achieved with a symbolic link, but that will fail here for the same reason calling the copy `eip` failed in the first place:

```
ek@Io:~$ ln -s /bin/ip eip
ek@Io:~$ ./eip
Object "p" is unknown, try "ip help".
```

(I made a symbolic link to my system's `/bin/ip`, but the same happens when you symlink to a separate copy.)

The solution is to write a wrapper script (named `eip`, or whatever you like) that invokes `ip`, passing its arguments along. The script file can look like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/your/ip "$@"
```

Comment: some more programs which require the same name are kmod,lsmod and rmmod. I just figured this out based on your explanation. It was nice working with you.

Comment: @sudheer It's actually somewhat common to have a program that behaves differently depending on its basename--see [`busybox`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/busybox.1.html) for an extreme example. `file $(which kmod lsod rmmod)` (and `kmod --help`), shows `kmod` is an executable but `lsmod` and `rmmod` (and others) are symlinks to it. What's uncommon is to use just *part* of one's basename rather than the whole--instead of just seeing if its basename is equal to any of several special names, `ip` checks its length and then uses the substring without the first two characters.