# What kind of link to /bin/systemctl is /sbin/reboot?

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link

Stupid question here. I see that `/sbin/reboot` seems to be a link to `/bin/systemctl`. However it does not behave as a "simple" link because calling `/bin/systemctl` is not the same as `/sbin/reboot`.

Also, although `/bin/systemctl` does have a `reboot` option, `/sbin/reboot` does not seem to be a simple alias to `/bin/systemctl reboot`, because for example `reboot --help` prints a specific help that cannot be reached with `/bin/systemctl reboot --help` (or `/bin/systemctl --help reboot`).

So what is this link and how to peek at its definition?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nice question, I found the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77030/201297), provided by [@slm ♦](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm), on Unix & Linux Q&A:

> Many programs make use of this technique where there is a single
>   executable that changes its behaviour based on how it was executed.
>
> There's typically a structure inside the program called a case/switch
>   statement that determines the name the executable was called with and
>   then will call the appropriate functionality for that executable name.
>   That name is usually the first argument the program receives.
>
> [Read the examples...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77030/201297)

While in the original answer are provided two examples with C and Perl, here is an example with Bash. In Bash the positional parameter `$0` contains the name of the script that is executed. So let's create a simple script, called `program.sh` and make it executable:

```bsh
cat << EOF > program.sh && chmod +x program.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "I was called as \"\${0##*/}\""
EOF
```

- `\$` will escape the special meaning of `$` within `cat` during the script creation.
- `${0##*/}` will output only the name of the executable without the path during the script execution.

Next let's create three symbolic links to that script:

```bsh
for link in call-{1..3}; do ln -s program.sh $link; done
```

Now, depending on how we call `program.sh` - directly or by any of the symbolic links, that we've created - the output will be different:

```
$ ./program.sh 
I was called as "program.sh"

$ ./call-1 
I was called as "call-1"

$ ./call-2
I was called as "call-2"

$ ./call-3
I was called as "call-3"
```

Answer (score 5):

As [pa4080 says](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023946/22949), it's just a normal [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), and [`systemctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/systemctl.1.html) itself is what checks what name it has been run as, in order to decide what action to perform. This sort of thing can be achieved with any mechanism that causes the same executable file to be run under multiple names; in practice, it is achieved through the use of [symlinks](http://foldoc.org/symlink) or [hard links](http://foldoc.org/hard+link). On GNU/Linux systems, like Ubuntu, it's most common to use symlinks for this purpose.

In Ubuntu releases with [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) (which currently includes all [supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Current) releases *except* 14.04 LTS, which uses [Upstart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart)), [not just the `reboot` command but also the `halt`, `poweroff`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/reboot.8.html), [`runlevel`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/runlevel.8.html), [`shutdown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/shutdown.8.html), and [`telinit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/telinit.8.html) commands are all symlinks to `/bin/systemctl`:

```
$ file /sbin/{halt,poweroff,reboot,runlevel,shutdown,telinit}
/sbin/halt:     symbolic link to /bin/systemctl
/sbin/poweroff: symbolic link to /bin/systemctl
/sbin/reboot:   symbolic link to /bin/systemctl
/sbin/runlevel: symbolic link to /bin/systemctl
/sbin/shutdown: symbolic link to /bin/systemctl
/sbin/telinit:  symbolic link to /bin/systemctl
```

The precise actions `systemctl` undertakes based on the name you use to run it, as well as other ways you can specify those actions, are explained in detail in [**this excellent answer**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/11938) by [JdeBP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5132/jdebp) to [What is the difference between these commands for bringing down a Linux server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195898/what-is-the-difference-between-these-commands-for-bringing-down-a-linux-server) on [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). As it explains, these commands (except `runlevel`) operate as shorthand for `systemctl isolate ...` commands with `...` replaced by different targets.

In case you're interested, the C code that considers what name you used to invoke `systemctl` in deciding what action to perform is located in the `parse_argv` function defined in [`systemctl.c`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~registry/systemd/master/view/head:/src/systemctl/systemctl.c), which currently starts on line 6972 of that file. To find it you can search for:

```c
static int parse_argv(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

The relevant parts span most of that function, but it all roughly resembles this fragment of it, continuing similarly but with different code for each string, and with some other checks and branching logic:

```c
                if (strstr(program_invocation_short_name, "halt")) {
                        arg_action = ACTION_HALT;
                        return halt_parse_argv(argc, argv);
                } else if (strstr(program_invocation_short_name, "poweroff")) {
                        arg_action = ACTION_POWEROFF;
                        return halt_parse_argv(argc, argv);
                } else if (strstr(program_invocation_short_name, "reboot")) {
```

Other examples of commands that examine how they were invoked to (sometimes) act differently include [`vim`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/vim.1.html), which behaves differently when run as `vim`, `ex`, `view`, `gvim`, `gview`, and several others; [`ip`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/ip.8.html), see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604230/error-object-ip-is-unknown-try-ip-help); [`gksu`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gksu.1.html), see [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21033/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-and-gksu); [`less`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/less.1.html), which [changes its appearance if named `more`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81131/11938) (but still lets you scroll bidirectionally, unlike Ubuntu's [`more`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/more.1.html)); [`busybox`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/busybox.1.html); and most [Bourne-style shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Bourne_shell), such as [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html) and [`zsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/zsh.1.html), which automatically behave more compatibly with [POSIX requirements for `sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) if run as `sh`.