# How to write a script that prints the absolute path of the current directory?

Tags: command-line

How can I write a script that prints the *absolute path* of the current working directory?

Comment: `pwd` .........

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Now go and post the shortest answer ever on this website.

Comment: You could post the word `pwd` as a link to [man pwd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pwd.1.html).

Comment: Alternatively: use the shell's builtin variable `echo "$PWD"`

Comment: @Jos: only if `pwd` wasn't first a built-in in most shells

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the directory from which the script is called you can use either the environment variable `$PWD` or the command `pwd` in most cases with command substitution like `$(pwd)`.

If you want to get the actual location of the script you can use the variable `$0` that contains the full script name (including the path).

Here is an example:

```bash
~$ cat /usr/local/bin/test-path.sh 
#/bin/sh
echo "${0}"     # full script name
echo "${0##*/}" # script name
echo "${0%/*}"  # script path
echo "$PWD"     # current working directory
echo "$(pwd)"   # current working directory
pwd             # current working directory
```

```bash
~$ test-path.sh
/usr/local/bin/test-path.sh
test-path.sh
/usr/local/bin
/home/pa4080
/home/pa4080
/home/pa4080
```

Here is one related topic: [What kind of link to /bin/systemctl is /sbin/reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1023939/566421)